# Calendar doesn't show up in add-on modules

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I've had no luck installing the Calendar.

After uploading the calendar folder to  /system/expressionengine/third_party/  and to ./themes/third_party/  - the calendar doesn't appear on the modules page.

I'm running EE v2.7.2 - Build Date: 20131008

Answer (score 2):

You have checked that you have a /calendar folder in both those locations and that there are files in them? look for mod.calendar.php,there should be 14 files and 4 folders in /system/expressionengine/third_party/calendar

Comment: Now I realize that I had misunderstood which folders that should be uploaded. I loaded up the whole Calendar1.8.5 to the specified folders. But when I followed the structure of Calendar1.8.5 I found the correct Calendar folders and uploaded them to their corresponding locations in my EE stucture. Everything is ok now. Thank you!